# Import-Module for custom dll fails

Tags: c#, powershell

I followed the demo [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saveenr/archive/2010/03/08/how-to-create-a-powershell-2-0-module-and-cmdlet-with-visual-studio-2010-screencast-included.aspx) for creating a custom powershell cmdlet. When I attempt to import the module, I get the following error:

```
C:\PS> Import-Module DemoPS.dll
Import-Module : The specified module 'DemoPS.dll' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
```

If anymore info is needed, let me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is shown because it can't find your dll file. You need to specify full path for your modules DLL file (e.g. `Import-Module c:\users\mj\desktop\DemoPS.dll`).

As an alternative solution, you can save it in your "module" folder. This is a folder called "Modules" that you have to create in your profile directory. Your profile directory can be found using `$profile`. It is normally in `C:\Users\<username>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\`. So to use this, place your dll in following path:

```
C:\Users\<username>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\DemoPS\DemoPS.dll
```